# Running a method with Arguments after clicking a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a left-hand pane consisting of a table in a master-detail storyboard setup.

I want to be able to click the cells (dynamically created from a database) and have them perform 2 segues.

I created a method that I want to run.

```
-(IBAction)cellClicked:(id)sender {
    //update detail screen
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showItemOrGroup1" sender:sender];

    //update nav
    NSString *navSegue = [NSString stringWithString:@"Level1"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:navSegue sender:sender];
```

This method basically performs one segue that changes the master table to a sub table, and another segue that changes the detail to some other view.

My question is how can I set up my custom UITableViewCell so that when I click it, the method will run and I will be able to give method information about the cell (the custom cell hold some parameters such as 'id' which I do not display).

I tried turning it into a UIControl but that didn't work
I also tried using UITapGestureRecognizer but it would not let me add arguments.
e.g.,

```
SEL cellSelector = @selector(cellClicked);
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:cellSelector];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Any suggestions on making it clickable or more optimal methods of solving the situation would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

==== EDIT =====

I tried didSelectRowAtIndex path but it seems that I get an odd error:

```
2013-12-12 11:38:45.974 Catsy[4772:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[EventModel<0x92ab0> init]: cannot init a class object.'
```

Below is what I wrote for didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    EventCell* sender = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self cellClicked:sender];
}
```

Below is my EventModel class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface EventModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger eventId;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger parentId;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger rootId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger sequence;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger levelNo;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger createdate;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger updatedate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *childrenIds;

/* =INSTANCE METHODS= */
-(id)init;
@end
```

and the .m

```
#import "EventModel.h"

@implementation EventModel

-(id)init {
    return [super init];
}
@end
```

==== CLARIFICATION OF SOLUTION ====

The problem resided in the fact that I was using "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" instead of "cellForRowAtIndexPath"…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableView has a delegate method `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` that will give you the index of the selected row.  With that you could perform any desired actions.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but it gave me an error. see my update above.

Comment: Could you add what your two segues are doing?  You shouldn't have to reach back your cell unless you need to change its appearance, and you should do it in `didSelectRowAtIndePath`.  Otherwise you should only use the index to update/query your model.  On a side note, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is used to create a new cell and should not be used to reach a cell.  If you need access to a cell, use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Rufel, Thanks so much! the answer had to do with your side note. When I used cellForRowAtIndexPath, My code worked charmingly. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents:

a) if You are using storyboard/segue, runtime will call the segue you set in storyboard, and AFTER "didSelectRowAtIndexPath": so be careful of the sequence.

b) If You stay with segue, you can prepare with "prepareForSegue"

c) You can eventually prevent calling segue responding "NO" to "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier" and calling segue manually using "performSegue.." in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and make all the logic you want...
set views, buttons, and after execute the segue OR push manually a controller.